# An elegant but difficult inequality.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, uvw, rearrangement-inequality

> $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+y}} + \frac{y}{\sqrt{y+z}} + \frac{z}{\sqrt{z+x}}$$
>   Over all non-negative $x,y,z$ satisfying $x+y+z=4$, let the maximum value of the above expression be $M$. What is the value of $\lfloor 10000M \rfloor$?

This is a question from [here](https://brilliant.org/problems/a-very-hard-inequality/?ref_id=1072366), and I decided to give it a go, bit got stuck. Here is my approach:
Let $x+y=u^2, y+z=v^2, z+x=w^2$. Hence, $u^2 + v^2 + w^2 =8$. Also, $x=4-v^2, y=4-w^2, z=4-u^2$ and the expression becomes 
$$\frac{4}{u} + \frac{4}{v} + \frac{4}{w} - \frac{v^2}{u} - \frac{w^2}{v} - \frac{u^2}{w} $$
I was itching to use Titu's Lemma/Cauchy-Schwarz in Engel form but then I realized that it will help provide a lower bound. With that ruled out, I am thinking of Rearrangement Inequality but my mind is pulling off a perfect blank. Any guidance will be welcome.

Note: The answer to the question is $25000$.

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximise+%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bx%2By%7D%7D+%2B+%5Cfrac%7By%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7By%2Bz%7D%7D+%2B+%5Cfrac%7Bz%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bz%2Bx%7D%7D+when+x%2By%2Bz%3D4), the maximum value of the expression occurs when $x=y=z=\frac{4}{3}$. Therefore $\lfloor 10000M \rfloor$ is $24494$, not $25000$.

Comment: Well, according to the link I included, the answer is supposed to be $25000$.

Comment: Okay I get you now. Because $x,y,z$ are nonnegative, it turns out that there is a greater value attained at $(x,y,z) = (3,1,0)$.